# Is there any way to make an object to be drawed blured?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there any way, to draw an object in WPF (particularly an Image) with an blur effect in any, relative easy way, like this

```
private void AnyObjectIWantToBeBlured_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
(sender as Image).Effect = System.Windows.Media.Effects.BlurEffect;
// i do know this one is not going to work
}
private void AnyObjectIWantTodeblure_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
(sender as Image).Effect = System.Windows.Media.Effects.NotBlur;
// and this one too
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: if you'd agree that blur ~ opacity, have a look at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2702f20f-68f6-4026-9b7f-d78a9443d146/give-a-button-the-disabled-look?forum=wpf)

Comment: @dlatikay well, not exactly, and even if so youre answer is a little, well, blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you almost did it yourself.

```
private void UIElement_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var uiElement = sender as UIElement;

    if (uiElement != null)
    {
        uiElement.Effect = new BlurEffect();
    }
}

private void UIElement_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var uiElement = sender as UIElement;

    if (uiElement != null)
    {
        uiElement.Effect = null;
    }
}
```

I would do it with a `Style` though.

```
<Style x:Key="BlurOnMouseOverStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <BlurEffect></BlurEffect>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

You don't need event handlers this way.

Comment: This is great! thank you! Why didn't i find that one on MSDN?
No, within my context its need to be done in code, because its should give **everyone else** blur effect